# gTTS Error When Code is Runned

Tags: python

```
    from gtts import gTTS
    import os
    tts=gTTS(text="Both are great",lang="en")
    tts.save("both.mp3")
    os.system("mpg12 both.mp3")
```

I am having this error,"cannot import name gTTS".

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing `gtts` module using the command `sudo pip install gtts`, your previous installation might be corrupt or missing some dependencies.